# Why modify Number.prototype.toString does not work?

Tags: javascript

In javascript, when using add sign (+) to concatenate a string and
another variable, that variable will implicitly call its `toString` method if it is not a `string`. To verify this, I made a constructor called Apple.

```
function Apple(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Apple.prototype.toString = function() {
    console.log('Apple.prototype.toString called.');
    return this.name;
};

var apple = new Apple('Thai apple');
var msg = apple + ' tastes good.'
console.log(msg)
```

It works as I expected: when calculating `apple + ' tastes good'`,
`Apple.prototype.toString` is called.
Then I did a similar experiment on `Number` type.

```
Number.prototype.num2str = Number.prototype.toString;
Number.prototype.toString = function() {
  console.log('new Number.prototype.toString called.');
  return this.num2str();
}

var msg = 'num = ' + 123;
console.log(msg);
```

After running it, I noticed that `Number.prototype.toString` is not called.
I'm confused. Why doesn't it work like the previous example?

Comment: Oh; sorry I'll delete my comment then~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why doesn't it work like the previous example?

`toString` is only called if the value is an *object* (but see below). `123` is not an object, it's a *primitive* (number) value. Converting primitive values to string values follows different rules. See [`§7.1.12`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-tostring-applied-to-the-number-type) in the ES2016 spec, and [`§7.1.12.1`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-tostring-applied-to-the-number-type) specifically numbers (too long to quote here) for how values are converted to strings.

Primitive values are *not* coerced to objects when the `+` operator is used.

---

However, even if you'd create a number *object* it wouldn't work. That's because `toString` is not actually called for number objects. Why is that?

[When performing additio](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus-runtime-semantics-evaluation)n, the following steps happen:

> [...]
>   5. Let *lprim* be ? ToPrimitive(*lval*).
>   6. Let *rprim* be ? ToPrimitive(*rval*).
>   [...]

Both values are converted to primitive values first *before* they are converted to a number or a string specifically (a primitive value can be a string, number, boolean, `null` or `undefined`).
Converting *objects* to primitive values this way will ultimately calls `valueOf` first. Only if the return value of that function is *not* a *primitive value* will `toString` be called.

Because `new Number(123).valueOf()` returns a primitive value, `toString` will not be called!

Here is your example adjusted for `valueOf`:

```js
Number.prototype.valueOf = function() {
  console.log('new Number.prototype.valueOf called.');
  return 'something';
}

var msg = 'num = ' + new Number(123);
console.log(msg);
```

---

**NB:** `toString` and `valueOf` are actually outdated ways of converting objects to strings/numbers/primitives. Since ES6, the new is to call the `@@toPrimitve` method of the object. Only if that doesn't exist, `toString` or `valueOf` will be called (see [`§7.1.1 ToPrimitive`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-toprimitive)).